# How to use style in another resources?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, resourcedictionary

I have a based style that target type is button call BaseButtonStyle in ResourceDictionaries/CustomControlStyles/BaseButtonStyle.xaml.

And I create a new button style that extended from BaseButtonStyle call AddButtonStyle.

Both styles I have added in App.xaml as followings.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--Buttons-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/CustomControlStyles/BaseButtonStyle.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/CustomControlStyles/AddButtonStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then I add a button that refer to AddButtonStyle but it raised an error

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key BaseButtonStyle

What's wong with my reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an absolute path: 
    "ms-appx:///ResourceDictionaries/CustomControlStyles/BaseButtonStyle.xaml"
Of course I don't know if that path fit your file location.

Comment: still doesn't work. I changed as >> <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///ResourceDictionaries/CustomControlStyles/BaseButtonStyle.xaml" /> Anyway, thank you for your very quickly reply.

Comment: Of course you have included these files in your solution?

Comment: yes. it is in my solution. so I have to exclude it?

Comment: Ok, so maybe try something else. Leave absolute paths in App.xaml but add
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseButtonStyle.xaml" />
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
inside AddButtonStyle.xaml file.

Comment: thanks. it will be another option. I still think it should work fine. Because when I did like this in WPF it work fine. Anyway, thank you very much.